# 3d.js - Tree graph - Multible Nodes to single end node

Tags: d3.js, graph, tree

I’m creating an nodes tree graph based on: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/01/tree-diagrams-in-d3js_11.html

What I’m not getting done, or finding out on google if it’s possible to direct multiple nodes to one end node, like in my sample image below.
Can sombody help me out? or point to the right direction?

Sample how I wanted.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyocN.png

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with this data source:

```
var treeData = [   {
    "name": "Top Level 1",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level 1",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
      }
    ]   },   {
    "name": "Top Level 2",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level 2"
      }
    ]   },   {
    "name": "Top Level 3",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level 3"
      }
    ]   } ];
```

Comment: Thanks,

but im only getting Top Level1, the rest is not showing...

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IoZ9k.png